# How to sample from large dataframe based on values in a column efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a medium sized dataset of 220k product titles with their brands, I want to take a sample from this dataframe such as for every brand, I take at least one product and at most 10 products.

Here is my code currently : The idea is to group by brand than aggregating through `count`, then iterating through the brand aggregated dataframe to sample at most 10 products from that brand.

```
def sample_brand_equally(df,random_state=42):
    grp_brand = df.groupby('brand').brand.count()
    samples = []
    for brand_name,brand_count in grp_brand.iteritems() : 
        if brand_count > 10:
            sample_size = 10
        else:
            sample_size = brand_count
        
        brand_sample = df[df.brand == brand_name].sample(sample_size,random_state=42)
        samples.append(brand_sample)
    return pd.concat(samples)
```

This functions takes more than 5 min to run on my laptop with a CPU of Ryzen 5 4000U working at 3.5 GHz which seems like a very long time for a not so big dataframe.

My questions is how to achieve this in a more efficient way (and maybe a more elegant way) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the conditional into a function `sample_brand_equally` and apply this function to the groups (they are dataframes as well) using `apply`:

```
def sample_brand_equally(grp, n, random_state=42):
    brand_count = grp.size
    if brand_count>n:
        sample_size = n
    else:
        sample_size = brand_count
    return grp.sample(n, random_state=random_state)


df.groupby("brand").apply(lambda x: sample_brand_equally(x, 10))
```

This should in general be faster than a for loop.

(See [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html))

---

OLD answer:
You could use [`DataFrameGroupBy.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)

To avoid having the sample size larger than the group size you could use a percent sample:

```
df.groupby("brand").sample(frac=.1, random_state=42)
```

As an alternative use sampling with replacement:

```
df.groupby("brand").sample(n=sample_size, random_state=42, replace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what I'm looking for, because I want to sample only 10 for groups having more than 10 elements, and for groups having less than 10 rows, than keep the whole group, so it's conditional.

Comment: @Annis99 please check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you, this is much faster !